# Is there any alternative for Round() in Python?

Tags: python, rounding

When I use round() to round the float value to 2 digits, and when numbers at the decimal places are zero, it displays only one of those places

eg. if I round(12.00,2), the result is like 12.0, it rounds off to one decimal place.

I would like my result with 2 decimal places, like 12.00

If there is any other function in python which can give me the result?

Comment: you should use formatting. Mathematically speaking `12.0`, `12.00`, `12.000` and so on are the same.

Comment: Use the right output [format](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding).

Comment: Note that `round()` isn't really relevant, try `print(12.00)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round` is not exactly what is giving you this result, mathematically speaking `12.0`, `12.00`, and `12.000` are the same value. Then, to achieve what you want you should use formatting.

If you are using Python 3.6+

```
>>> f'{round(12.00,2):.2f}'
'12.00'
```

If you are using a previous version of Python:

```
>>> '{number:.2f}'.format(number=round(12.00,2))
'12.00'
```

Even when you could use `%` for formatting, I strongly discourage following this practice. The best way to handle formatting is to use f-strings, if not possible, use the `format` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting. You can specify the number of decimal places and if it needs to cut off numbers it will round.

Below formats to two decimal places.

```
num = 12.000
'%.2f' % num # => 12.00

num = 12.005
'%.2f' % num # => 12.01
```